# How to move points of a line to specific locations?

Tags: python, tkinter, line

I'm trying visualise the sine waves addition in python using tkinter, and I'm trying to build lines between each circles center, but what I've tried so far didnt work as I thought it would. is there a way to fix what I've tried (see code), or a way to move only one coordinates point of a line independantly from the other?

As you'll see in the code if you run it, I've tried a method where each iteration the previous line is erased and a new one is created. When I run the code there is actually a line between each center of the circles just like I want, but facts are those lines persist and won't erase themselves; for some reason it seems like the canvas.delete(line) doesnt work as I expected it to.

here's the full code. The interesting part is in the 'updateline' fonction, into 'act()' func.

```
import math
import tkinter as tk

##important to know! -- the way I'm creating the circles is by setting an object, the bounds of the circle, depending on amplitude asked by user.
##then the programs calculates the path of these bounds, depending on circles, amplitude, phase and frequency of the sine waves asked by the user from the tkinter GUI.
##finally, the program creates and moves along this path a circle, representing visually the sine wave.

top = tk.Tk()
top.title('Superposition')
choice = tk.Tk()
choice.title('Parametres')

f = tk.Frame(choice,bd=3)
f.pack(side='top')

g = tk.Frame(choice,bd=3)
g.pack(side='bottom')

tk.Label(f,text="nbre ondes:",width = 10).grid(row=0,column=0)
sines = tk.Spinbox(f,from_=1,to=50,width=10,textvariable=tk.DoubleVar(value=2))
sines.grid(row=0,column=1)
sines.delete(0,5)
sines.insert(0,2)

delai = tk.Scale(g, orient='vertical', from_=100, to=1,resolution=1, length=100,label='delai')
delai.grid(row=0,column=0)
hauteur = tk.Scale(g, orient='vertical', from_=1100, to=100,resolution=100, length=100,label='fenetre')
hauteur.grid(row=0,column=1)
taillec1 = tk.Scale(g, orient='vertical', from_=3.5, to=0.1,resolution=0.1, length=100,label='taille')
taillec1.grid(row=0,column=2)
delai.set(20)
hauteur.set(600)
taillec1.set(1.5)

def grilledechoix():
    numberofsines = int(sines.get())
    for i in f.grid_slaves():
        if int(i.grid_info()["row"]) > numberofsines+2:
            i.grid_forget()

    for i in range(1,numberofsines+1):
        tk.Label(f,text="phase n."+str(i),width = 10).grid(row=i+2,column=4)
        phase = tk.Spinbox(f,from_=-180,to=180,width=10)
        phase.grid(row=i+2,column=5)
        phase.delete(0,5)
        phase.insert(0, 0)
    for i in range(1,numberofsines+1):
        tk.Label(f,text="amp. n."+str(i),width = 10).grid(row=i+2,column=0)
        ampli = tk.Spinbox(f,from_=1,to=10000000,width=10)
        ampli.grid(row=i+2,column=1)
        ampli.delete(0,5)
        ampli.insert(0,10)
    for i in range(1,numberofsines+1):
        tk.Label(f,text="freq n."+str(i),width = 10).grid(row=i+2,column=2)
        freq = tk.Spinbox(f,from_=-1000,to=1000,width=10)
        freq.grid(row=i+2,column=3)
        freq.delete(0,5)
        freq.insert(0,5)


def act():        
    h = g.grid_slaves()[1].get()
    delai = g.grid_slaves()[2].get()
    taillec1 = g.grid_slaves()[0].get()
    w = h

    ampdict = {'box1':100 * ((h/700)*taillec1)}
    frqdict = {}
    aaadict = {}
    fffdict = {}
    phadict = {}

    numberofsines = int(sines.get())

    sin = lambda degs: math.sin(math.radians(degs))
    cos = lambda degs: math.cos(math.radians(degs))

    for i in range(1,numberofsines+1):
        fffdict['box'+str(numberofsines-i+1)] = f.grid_slaves()[(2*i)-2].get()
        aaadict['box'+str(numberofsines-i+1)] = f.grid_slaves()[(2*i)-2+2*numberofsines].get()
        phadict['box'+str(numberofsines-i+1)] = f.grid_slaves()[(2*i)-2+4*numberofsines].get()
    for i in range(1,numberofsines+1):
        ampdict['box'+str(i)] = (float(ampdict['box1'])/float(aaadict['box1'])) * float(aaadict['box'+str(i)])
        frqdict['box'+str(i)] = float(fffdict['box'+str(i)])/float(fffdict['box1'])

    class obj(object):
        cos0, cos180 = cos(0), cos(180)
        sin90, sin270 = sin(90), sin(270)

        def __init__(i, x, y, rayon):
            i.x, i.y = x, y
            i.rayon = rayon

        def bounds(i):
            return (i.x + i.rayon*i.cos0,   i.y + i.rayon*i.sin270,
                    i.x + i.rayon*i.cos180, i.y + i.rayon*i.sin90)

    def updateposition(canvas, id, cent, obj, path):
        obj.x, obj.y = next(path)
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(id)
        oldx, oldy = (x0+x1) // 2, (y0+y1) // 2
        dx, dy = obj.x - oldx, obj.y - oldy
        canvas.move(id, dx, dy)
        canvas.move(cent, dx, dy)
        canvas.after(delai, updateposition, canvas, id, cent, obj, path)

    def updateline(canvas, line, robj0, cent0, robj1, cent1):
        x00, y00, x01, y01 = canvas.coords(cent0)  ##defining coords of the two ovals asked, representing centers of circles
        x10, y10, x11, y11 = canvas.coords(cent1)
        oldx0, oldy0 = (x00+x01) // 2, (y00+y01) // 2 ##defining center coords of the two ovals
        oldx1, oldy1 = (x10+x11) // 2, (y10+y11) // 2
        dx0, dy0 = robj0.x - oldx0, robj0.y - oldy0 ##defining the deltax and deltay, difference of movements between frames, of the two ovals
        dx1, dy1 = robj1.x - oldx1, robj1.y - oldy1
        canvas.after(delai, canvas.delete, line) ##deleting previous line, does not work and I don't know why. I've also tried 'canvas.delete(line)', giving same results
        canvas.create_line(oldx0+dx0, oldy0+dy0, oldx1+dx1, oldy1+dy1) ##creating new line
        canvas.after(delai, updateline, canvas, line, robj0, cent0, robj1, cent1) ##function invoking itself after delay 'delai'

    def posobj(pt,ang,deltang):
        while True:
            yield pt.x + pt.rayon*cos(ang), pt.y + pt.rayon*sin(ang)
            ang = (ang+deltang)%360

    try:
        top.pack_slaves()[0].destroy()
    except:
        pass

    canvas = tk.Canvas(top, bg='white', height=h, width=w)
    canvas.pack(side='right')

    robj = {}
    r = {}
    posobjet = {}
    line = {}
    cent = {}

## the following 'for' loop creates a number of circles corresponding to sine waves, as much as the user asked.
    for i in range(1,int(sines.get())+2):
        if i != int(sines.get())+1:
            if i == 1:
                robj[str(i)] = obj(h/2,h/2,float(ampdict['box'+str(i)]))
                r[str(i)] = canvas.create_oval(robj[str(i)].bounds(),fill='',outline='black')
                cent[str(i)] = canvas.create_oval(h/2+h/200,h/2+h/200.,h/2-h/200,h/2-h/200, fill='white', outline='red')
                posobjet[str(i)] = posobj(robj[str(i)],float(phadict['box'+str(i)]),float(frqdict['box'+str(i)]))
            else:
                robj[str(i)] = obj(robj[str(i-1)].x,robj[str(i-1)].y,float(ampdict['box'+str(i)]))
                r[str(i)] = canvas.create_oval(robj[str(i)].bounds(),fill='',outline='black')
                cent[str(i)] = canvas.create_oval(robj[str(i)].x+h/200,robj[str(i)].y+h/200,robj[str(i)].x-h/200,robj[str(i)].y-h/200, fill='white', outline='blue')
                line[str(i)] = canvas.create_line(0,0,0,0)
                posobjet[str(i)] = posobj(robj[str(i)],float(phadict['box'+str(i)]),float(frqdict['box'+str(i)]))
                top.after(delai, updateposition, canvas, r[str(i)], cent[str(i)], robj[str(i)], posobjet[str(i-1)])
                ##here I'm invoking the updateline function using the constant 'delai', the line i, and objects defining the bounds of the center objects, the little blue/red dots appearing as the center of each circles(run the code, it'll be easier to understand)
                top.after(delai, updateline, canvas, line[str(i)], robj[str(i-1)], cent[str(i-1)], robj[str(i)], cent[str(i)])
        else:
            robj[str(i)] = obj(robj[str(i-1)].x,robj[str(i-1)].y,h/200)
            r[str(i)] = canvas.create_oval(robj[str(i)].bounds(),fill='white',outline='red')
            cent[str(i)] = canvas.create_oval(robj[str(i)].x+h/200,robj[str(i)].y+h/200,robj[str(i)].x-h/200,robj[str(i)].y-h/200, fill='white', outline='red')
            line[str(i)] = canvas.create_line(0,0,0,0)
            top.after(delai, updateposition, canvas, r[str(i)], cent[str(i)], robj[str(i)], posobjet[str(i-1)])
            ##2nd and last time invoking the updateline function, for the line between the last circle's point and the final red point.
            top.after(delai, updateline, canvas, line[str(i)], robj[str(i-1)], cent[str(i-1)], robj[str(i)], cent[str(i)])
    top.mainloop()

ok = tk.Button(f,text='NBRE',command=grilledechoix)
ok.grid(row=0,column=2)
ac = tk.Button(f,text='APPLY',command=act)
ac.grid(row=0,column=3)
grilledechoix()
act()
```

I expected the lines to disappear once the updateline function called itself again, because of that 'canvas.delete(line)' line into updateline, and I can't really understand why it does that. 
anyway if you have a solution to make the lines move, without creating and deleting them each time the function is called, feel free to tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems complete and reproducible, which is is not frequent for new users - thank you! But there's hardly any comments and the codebase is pretty large... Can you edit your code block and add comments?

Comment: sure, sorry. I've edited so that the function where there's the problem is fully explained and the 2 moments where I invoke the function updateline are commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I believe the issue is with this code:

```
canvas.after(delai, canvas.delete, line)
canvas.create_line(oldx0+dx0, oldy0+dy0, oldx1+dx1, oldy1+dy1)
canvas.after(delai, updateline, canvas, line, robj0, cent0, robj1, cent1)
```

It fails to reassign the *new* line to the `line` variable for the next call.  Instead try:

```
canvas.after(delai, canvas.delete, line)
line = canvas.create_line(oldx0+dx0, oldy0+dy0, oldx1+dx1, oldy1+dy1)
canvas.after(delai, updateline, canvas, line, robj0, cent0, robj1, cent1)
```

Which gets rid of the extra lines when I run it.  Let me know if I've missed the point.

Comment: thanks! You totally didn't miss the point, that was exactly what was I searching. I'm 'coding' since only 1 month and a half, and I can't understand the logic behind it, why does the call of a lambda function solves the problem?

Comment: I thought the arguments after the function were taken in count with the function, from what my tests with after() resulted in.

Comment: @foriinme, you appear to be correct about `after()` -- the references I checked were inconsistent about this.  I've updated my code accordingly.  It was likely primarily the issue of not reassigning the `line` variable.  But do confirm!

Comment: this explains why it did actualize the other point of the line's coordinates, the problem may come from the function deleting a variable - line - and creating another but trying to re-delete that same it deleted. thanks a lot, you really enlighted me on my own code :)

Comment: btw, I have no clue why it does that as the previous line is deleted before, but the code you edited, without the lambda function call, makes two lines instead of one